# vncdotool cannot connect to remote vnc server python

Tags: python, pip, python-3.7, vnc-server, vnc-viewer

Im stuck in this error and i dont know why im getting this error. I successfully installed all the pre-requirements in using the vncdotool and i read that they support python 3 now. Im using RealVNC but i guess that does not matter.
Here's the error below.

```
client = api.connect('vnchost:192.168.1.19:5800',password='pw@0987676')
```

```
client.captureScreen('screenshot.png')
client.keyPress('enter')

File "C:\Python3.7.4\lib\site-packages\vncdotool\api.py", line 108, in proxy_call
    raise VNCDoException(result)
vncdotool.api.VNCDoException: [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'twisted.internet.error.DNSLookupError'>: DNS lookup failed: vnchost.
]
```

Comment: Try [`api.connect('192.168.1.19::5800'…`](https://github.com/sibson/vncdotool/blob/4637bb95a5e12870829c819d2c23f70f29d4fbbe/vncdotool/command.py#L285)

Comment: Still same error sir. 
here's the output.
https://ibb.co/fNX7qPf

Comment: Do you still use `vnchost:` as a prefix? In my fix there is no any `vnchost`.

Comment: Mybad, here's the output when i run without prefix. Some ip :portnumber below is the output. Single colon
https://ibb.co/KsZVdyg
But when using ::PORTNUMBER double collon the program just stuck no output/ no error also.
Can you guide me sir?

Comment: When i remote it manually with real vnc on application i can remote with the same ip and port number. but in the program itself it can't.

Comment: Already solved. The other PC block the port that i was using. Now I'm having the next problem. Just timeout error I will still search for answers. If anyone has ever done this please guide me. Thanks.